# Write Nmap XML Scans in a File and compare them

Tags: python, python-3.6, nmap

I'm still pretty fresh about Python. I have packed two Nmap scans into an XML each and would like to compare them. It's about which Mac addresses do NOT appear in both scans.

But now I already have the problem when reading the first one that it gives me the error:
`02:10:18:09:E0:DC 7C:8B:CA:17:6D:28 Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/naseweis/Documents/Nmap/compare.py", line 17, in <module> mac=adress[1].attributes["addr"] IndexError: list index out of range`

t gives me the first two Mac addresses correctly. Since Nmap saves its own address without a Mac address (i.e. only IP). If the line soert is missing and the said error message appears
I know why the error occurs but unfortunately I don't know how to solve it in the code. It's great if you help me. I think the problem is that I am addressing the whole thing statically here `mac = address [1] .attributes ["addr"]`. Unfortunately I don't know how to solve it nicely.

```
# Compare 2 Scans
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc1=minidom.parse("file.xml")
hosts=xmldoc1.getElementsByTagName('host')

for host in hosts:
    adress=host.getElementsByTagName("address")
    if adress:
        mac=adress[1].attributes["addr"]
        MAC=mac.value
        print("%s"%(MAC))
```

`

```
file.xml
[code]?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE nmaprun>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/bin/../share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 7.91 scan initiated Fri Sep 24 17:22:47 2021 as: nmap -sn -oX ./Documents/Nmap/file.xml 192.168.0.0/24 -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="nmap -sn -oX ./Documents/Nmap/file.xml 192.168.0.0/24" start="1632500567" startstr="Fri Sep 24 17:22:47 2021" version="7.91" xmloutputversion="1.05">
<verbose level="0"/>
<debugging level="0"/>
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.0.1" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="02:10:18:09:E0:DC" addrtype="mac"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="kabelbox" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="10411" rttvar="8438" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.0.28" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="7C:8B:CA:17:6D:28" addrtype="mac" vendor="Tp-link Technologies"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="DESKTOP-2A5NKMC" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="256230" rttvar="256230" to="1281150"/>
</host>
<host><status state="up" reason="arp-response" reason_ttl="0"/>
<address addr="192.168.0.90" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<address addr="7C:0B:C6:40:B2:B0" addrtype="mac" vendor="Samsung Electronics"/>
<hostnames>
<hostname name="android-e857b307fef24a39" type="PTR"/>
</hostnames>
<times srtt="184769" rttvar="161219" to="829645"/>
</host>
<runstats><finished time="1632500571" timestr="Fri Sep 24 17:22:51 2021" summary="Nmap done at Fri Sep 24 17:22:51 2021; 256 IP addresses (4 hosts up) scanned in 4.39 seconds" elapsed="4.39" exit="success"/><hosts up="4" down="252" total="256"/>
</runstats>
</nmaprun>
```

Thanks for Help

Comment: you should check `if len(adress) > 1:` or `if len(adress) >= 2:` before using `adress[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You expect 2 addresses in host - so you should check `len()`

```
if len(adress) > 1:  # if len(adress) >= 2:
   mac = adress[1].attributes["addr"]
   # ... rest ...
else:
   print('There is no MAC address')
```